# Set year easily SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to set only year value of all tupples easily without changing other values?

I have a column D_MODE_DATE and its format is as follow.

```
26-MAR-11 20:26:17
```

forwarded 4 years look like this.

26-MAR-15 20:26:17

Usng Oracle 11G.

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(D_MODE_DATE,4*12)`

Answer (score 1):

Since a year has 12 months you can use ADD_MONTHS

```
with t as (
  select to_date('26-MAR-11 20:26:17', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') dd from dual
)
select dd, ADD_MONTHS(dd, 48) dd1 from t

    DD         DD1
----------------------
03/26/2011  03/26/2015
```

Comment: Cool, but why use a `CTE`?

Comment: I use it always, it helps me to separate my data from the solution I provide.